# Google Play "Licensing Library" / "Market Licensing package" missing from SDK manager

Tags: android

Do I not see packages like "Google Play Licensing Library" or "Google APIs" (to set up emulator for google-play).   I tried to clear the cache and reload with no success.  Is there some way I can manually download and install these packages?

( http://optionpeer.com/jimt/capture.png )

Comment: Do you have the "Updates/New" and "Installed" CheckBoxes checked? Did you try to run SDK Manager as Administrator?

Comment: had both check boxes checked, running as admin: no difference.  thanks for the ideas.  i would like to bypass the manager and install manually to get the GUI manager out of my way -- i've done this with Eclipse in the past. Where might those package zip be downloaded from ?

Comment: the issues seems to lie either in the ADT platform install or perhaps some corruption that occurred.  When I installed ADT plugin in eclipse indigo, i was able to see the missing packages, so i can continue with Indigo.  perhaps i'll try to re-install the Android ADT Eclipse and see if it clears (locally install corrupted, vs. Andoid ADT problem).

Answer (score 0):

Just run '/tools/android --clear-cache'