# Android SDK Manager missing extras, how can I get Google Market Licensing Library

Tags: android, eclipse

For some reason my Android SDK Manager has just a few Extras. The one I'm interested in is Google Marketing License Library. How can I add this ?

Back in December '14 I updated the SDK from 22.6.2 to a newer version
but that caused some  incompatibility errors when eclipse started up so I
used a back up to restore the 22.6.2 version.
I'm reluctant to try another upgrade because the last one went so bad and
wasted so much of my time...

I'd post an image of my SDK but stackoverflow says I don't have enough reputation points so here's what it says

```
Android SDK Tools   22.6.2  Update available: rev 24.0.2
Android SDK Plat... 19.0.1  Update available: rev. 20
.
.
.
Extras
    Android Support Library         19.1 installed
    Google Play services for Froyo  12 installed
    Google Play services            21 installed
    Usb Driver                      10 installed
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24986598/google-play-licensing-library-market-licensing-package-missing-from-sdk-ma

Comment: I read that entry, but based on my previous really bad experience upgrading I would rather not do that.